# How to make one table from two tables in SQL

Tags: sql, csv, phpmyadmin

I have two tables in MySQL, which I want to combine into one big table. Both tables have exactly the same columns(A primary index `id` column and a `snippet` column which is a string), but with different data. They have been loaded from different .csv files, because when not split the file was too big to upload to phpMyAdmin in one go.

Now, I want to combine these two tables back to one.

All the questions on StackOverflow that I could find so far are about wanting to combine the results of two tables.

For example: Map some data from one table to the other. But I want to physically merge the two tables so they are stored as one SQL table.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example for you

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
  AS (SELECT * FROM first UNION ALL SELECT * FROM second);
```

Comment: This solution worked, as soon as I removed the brackets. But that's probably just the difference between SQL versions. (I don't understand why the brackets would make it fail). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I might suggest that you just insert the second table into the first:

```
insert into first
    select * from second;
```

This allows you to keep auxiliary information about the first table -- such as primary key definitions, indexes, triggers, and foreign key relationships.

You can do something similar with:

```
create table newtable like first;

insert into newtable
    select * from first;

insert into newstable
    select * from second;
```

Note:  Usually I recommend using column lists when using `insert`, but if the two tables really do have exactly the same format, then this should work.

Also note that conflicts between the primary keys in the two tables could cause these methods to fail.